# Problems with loading csv file (Coding=UCS2) into self made table

Tags: mysql, csv

I try to "automatically" import the data from a csv (which is UCS-2 LE Bom coded) into a table I created before. But everytime I try to import the data via commandline I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8mb4 character string: ''  0.016 sec
```

Here´s the query I create the table with and try to insert the data with:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Import`;
CREATE TABLE `Import` (
`orderdate` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
`Kampagne` INT(7) DEFAULT NULL,
`Kampagnename` VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT NULL, 
`sent(overall)` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL, 
`number of E-Mails` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL, 
`BouncesÄ (overall)` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`openedÜ (overall)` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`On mobileÖ (overall)` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`clicks` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`clicks mobile` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`sold` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`Complaints (overall)`INT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`logged out(overall)` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`money` INT(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`rateOne%` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
`rateTwo%` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
`Bouncerate %` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
`Openrate%` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
`Openrate(mobil) %` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL, 
`clickrate %` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
`clickrate (mobil) %` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
`soldrate %` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
`rateThree %` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
`rateFour %` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UCS2;


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Test/Report.csv' INTO TABLE `Import` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Does anyone has an idea where the porblem is?

PS: The columns in the CSV named have the same "names" like the ones in the created table.

Data from CSV-File

```
orderdate;Kampagne;Kampagnename;sent(overall);number of E-Mails;BouncesÄ (overall);openedÜ (overall);On mobileÖ (overall);clicks;clicks mobile;sold;Complaints (overall);logged out(overall);money;rateOne%;rateTwo%;Bouncerate %;Openrate%;Openrate(mobil) %;clickrate %;clickrate (mobil) %;soldrate %;rateThree %;rateFour %
2016-12-07 10:03;2131466;20161207_1002_LC_YoBirthdayYes_LCAll_FR;20;20;0;6;3;1;0;0;0;0;0;100;100;0;30;15;5;0;0;0;0
2016-12-07 10:03;2131467;20161207_1002_LC_YoBirthdayYes_LCAll_UK;9;9;0;5;4;1;1;0;0;0;0;90;100;0;55.6;44.4;11.1;11.1;0;0;0
2016-12-07 10:03;2131465;20161207_1002_LC_YoBirthdayYes_LCAll_CH;11;11;0;4;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;91.7;100;0;36.4;18.2;0;0;0;0;0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the LOAD statement you need to specify the file character set using the `CHARACTER SET charset_name` clause. Otherwise the default character set is used (from the message in your case - utf8mb4). You can consult the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Test/Report.csv' INTO TABLE `Import` 
CHARACTER SET 'UCS2'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Both `ucs2` and `utf8mb4` are unicode character sets, but they are not compatible. `usc2` uses two byte character sequences, while utf8mb4 uses variable length - up to 4 byte character sequences to encode the characters.

If your file has Windows-style line terminators (CRLF), you need to convert it. One way to do it is to use Unix/Linux `tr` command:

```
tr -d '\r' inputfile.txt outputfile.txt
```

**Note about line endings**

To understand what line endings your file uses, open it in Notepad++ (Windows only) and select from the menu: Edit -> EOL Conversion. There are three items. The grayed item shows what is the style of your file. You can directly convert it in Notepad++ by selecting the "Unix (LF)" option and saving the file.

**Suggestion**

I would suggest that you name the columns using simple names without special characters and spaces. This way it is easier when you refer them in the SQL. As they are now, you will have to always quote the column names. When you need to have "business-meaning" column names, you can use alias in the select.

Comment: now 50% of my problem is solved: the data is importet but put into the first row in the first column: where is the problem here?

Comment: Please add also extract from your data into the question.

Comment: Edited the response to suggest converting the file to Unix-style line endings. Also check the field actual terminating character in the file is what you specified (semicolon) in the LOAD DATA statement.

Comment: where/how can I see if the file has Windows-style line terminators?

Comment: If you are using Windows, open the file in Notepad++ and select from the menu: Edit -> EOL Conversion. There are three items. The grayed item shows what is the style of your file. You can directly convert it in Notepad++ by selecting the "Unix (LF)" option and saving the file.

Comment: Reading your question one more time, I realize that your CSV file most likely contains header with column names. You need to instruct MySQL to skip this, by adding IGNORE 1 LINES at the end of your statement. See the edited version of my answer.

Comment: I added the ignore 1 Lines part - but now got no entries in the table... I added some extraced data to question

Comment: Your date column is not a complete date. Try using a CHAR or VARCHAR column instead. What is the message after the import is finished?

Comment: ok - now the import workt 75% (I converted the Windows-Style line terminator to Unic): The number of filled rows is correct now, but the entries are not correct (looks a bit like mandarin). I get this warning: 
76 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s):
1366 Incorrect integer value: '㈱㌱㐶㜻㈰ㄶㄲ〷弱〰㉟䱃彙潂楲瑨摡祙敳彌䍁汬录䬻㤻㤻〻㔻㐻ㄻㄻ〻〻〻〻㤰' for column 'Kampagne' at row 1
1366 Incorrect integer value: '㐴⸴' for column 'sent(overall)' at row 1...

Records: 76  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1747 0.000 sec

Comment: Open the file in Notepad++, click "Encoding" menu and see which option is selected.

Comment: ok-my mistake: I selected ANSI...now I changed it back to UCS-2 again and the line terminators are (still) UNIX: and now the table is not filled again...

Comment: Does the file look OK in Notepad++? You should use the "Convert to ..." option to change the encoding. Otherwise it become messy. If you have the original file, I suggest that you start over :)